Specify grepTags on the command line with ng e2e
In our angular project, we are using cypress-grep package to filter tests.
We have a test module which specifies the grepTags and then references some existing tests, approximately as follows:
import cypressGrep from '@cypress/grep'

Cypress.env('grepTags', '@smoke');
cypressGrep();

context('cypress/e2e/Test1.cy.ts', () =>
  require('cypress/e2e/Test1.cy.ts'))
context('cypress/e2e/Test2.cy.ts', () =>
  require('cypress/e2e/Test2.cy.ts'))
context('cypress/e2e/Test3.cy.ts', () =>
  require('cypress/e2e/Test3.cy.ts'))

We are starting the test using ng e2e command, using the --spec parameter to select the test files.
For example:
ng e2e --spec **/smoketest/*.cy.ts

As an alternative, I think it would be better to specify the tags externally, on the command line, something like
set grepTags=@smoke
ng e2e

Ultimately I would like to specify the tags in a build pipeling (we are using Azure Devops).
So far I have not found a way to make this work.
Is it possible?

According to the docs you can add the grep option to the command line line so:
# run tests tagged @fast
$ npx cypress run --env grepTags=@fast
# run only the tests tagged "smoke"
# that have "login" in their titles
$ npx cypress run --env grep=login,grepTags=smoke

so all you would need is the following (since --spec is working)
ng e2e --spec **/smoketest/*.cy.ts --env grepTags=@smoke


If I specify --env with the command ng e2e I get the error message Error: Unknown argument: env

This used to work - here in the Cypress repository is the type definition showing the available options (env is one), and builder implementation is here. I will check out latest version and post an answer if I can get a working example.


You're incorrectly setting the grepTags. You will need to pass the tags into the describe/context/it blocks, instead of setting the Cypress environment variables.


You can use any way to modify the environment values grep and grepTags, except the run-time Cypress.env('grep') (because it is too late at run-time).
(Source: Cypress)

Instead, you can pass in the tags like so:
context('cypress/e2e/Test1.cy.ts', { tags: '@smoke' }, () =>
  require('cypress/e2e/Test1.cy.ts'))


I'm not familiar enough with ng e2e to give guidance on if there is a way for you to pass in the Cypress environment variables in via that command. (Using the Cypress command directly, does expose this: npx cypress run --env grepTags=@smoke). However, Cypress environment variables can be set on the command line, simply by prefacing the variable name with CYPRESS_ or cypress_. In this case, you'd want to set CYPRESS_grepTags=@smoke.


I had already tried using set CYPRESS_grepTags=@smoke followed by ng e2e and it did not work. Now I have found that it does work if I open a Windows command prompt and enter the command there, but it doesn't work in a terminal window inside Visual Studio Code.

Got it! The terminal in Visual Studio Code is a Power Shell terminal. The command to set the environment variable is $env:CYPRESS_grepTags='@smoke'. Now it works in VS Code as well.
